# Lookahead in JavaScript regex

Tags: regex, regex-lookarounds

Using JavaScript, I am trying to replace an attribute inside an html tag, and have come up with this regex:

```
/<\s*tag[^>]*(attr)=['"]{1,1}([^'"\s]*)['"]{1,1}/ig;
```

This works.  However, I want to be able to specify to look for the same type of quotation mark enclosing the attribute value.  So, for example, I want to specify if this is the form `<tag attr='data'>`, to look in the SECOND quotation mark for the single one, not the double one.  The inverse case, `<tag attr="data">` would be similar; match the SECOND mark with double quotes, not single ones.  This is to help me protect the function call against strangely formed HTML.

So, how can I achieve this?

Thanks!

Comment: Wouldn't using the DOM make more sense?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try this:

```
/<tag[^>]*attr=(['"])(?:(?!\1)\S)*\1/ig;
```

**Explanation:**

```
<tag     # Match <tag (\s* is not needed since whitespace is illegal here)
[^>]*    # Match any non-> characters
attr=    # Match "attr="
(['"])   # Match a quote, remember which kind; {1,1} can be dropped (it's a no-op)
(?:      # Try to match
 (?!\1)  #  (unless it's the corresponding closing quote)
 \S      #  any non-whitespace character
)*       # any number of times
\1       # Match the corresponding closing quote
```

Comment: Awesome.  Thanks for the explanation!  Really makes it better for me, that way I can learn how to incorporate that into other regexes.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
/<\s*tag[^>]*(attr)=(['"]{1,1})([^'"\s]*)\2{1,1}/ig;
```