# Javascript regex lookahead syntax

Tags: javascript, regex

I have the following regex which I'm applying to multiple url's on my page.

```
(/Services\/(.*?)\/People\/(.*?(?=(\.aspx)))/gi)
```

What I was trying to do was to match and then replace a url structure that looks like the following example:

```
/Services/FoodService/People/JoeBloggs.aspx
```

I have the regex working until the lookahead for the .aspx. So any help in spotting what the error with my lookahead is would be much appreciated!

```
var res = str.match(/Services\/(.*?)\/People\/(.*?(?=(\.aspx)))/gi);
```

I've broken down the bit I'm having problems with below:

```
(.*? (?=(\.aspx)))
```

Any character:

```
.*?
```

As long as the lookahead finds an instance of

```
.aspx
```

I've checked out these posts as well, but I'm still struggling so all help appreciated!

[Lookahead in JavaScript regex](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12466262/lookahead-in-javascript-regex)

[Lookahead in Regex](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14760355/lookahead-in-regex?rq=1)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use this regex:

```
\/Services\/(.*?)\/People\/(.*?(?=\.aspx))
```

#### [RegEx Demo](http://regex101.com/r/rP2iF1/1)

Comment: Glad it helped. If you don't want to capture `JoeBloggs` then you can also use: `\/Services\/(.*?)\/People\/(?=.*?\.aspx))` regex.